# Core Data - Magical Record - Creating an Entity, updating, and saving it

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I really don't understand why this is giving me so much trouble. I am using Magical Record's Core Data wrapper to create entities, update and save them. 
I am able to create and fetch entities perfectly, fine. A created entity well be persisted, however, I am not able to make changes to an entity and have those changes persist once the app is terminated. Here is how I am setting up Magical Record.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];

    return YES;
}
```

When my app terminates

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [MagicalRecord cleanUp];
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
}
```

How I create my entity

```
   //Create a new payment entity and save it to the persistant data store, dismiss view controller upon saving
        PaymentEntity *newPaymentEntity = [PaymentEntity MR_createEntity];
        newPaymentEntity.title = self.titleTextField.text;
        newPaymentEntity.paymentAmount = self.amountOwedTextField.text;
        newPaymentEntity.notes = self.notesTextView.text;
        newPaymentEntity.debtors = self.debtorsArray;
        newPaymentEntity.createdAt = [NSDate date];
        newPaymentEntity.isPayed = NO;
        if (self.setDueDateSwitch.on)
            newPaymentEntity.dueDate = self.dueDate;
        else
            newPaymentEntity.dueDate = nil;

        [newPaymentEntity.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
            }
            else{
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }];
```

And how I am attempting to save changes to my entity.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        PaymentEntity *payment = [self.payment MR_inContext:localContext];
        payment.amountPayed = self.amountPayedLabel.text;
        payment.debtors = self.debtorsArray;

        [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    }];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Like I said, once I create an entity it persists, however all changes I make to an entity do not persist once the app is terminated.